# Filter search list when item not available in Firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I was added searchbar, when i want input a data that data is not available in firestore then TextView noDocumentAvailable is visible and when i want input a data that data is available in firestore then TextView is Gone.

Code :

```
private void searchDocument(String search) {
    collectionReference.orderBy("documentName").startAt(search).endAt(search + '\uf8ff').get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                documentsList.clear();

                if (task.getResult().size() < 0) { // not working for me
                    noDocumentAvailable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                        Documents documents = documentSnapshot.toObject(Documents.class);
                        documentsList.add(documents);
                        documentListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(StartCounting.this, "Error : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `task.getResult().size()` can never return a negative value.

Comment: Do you have the best way to solve that problem? @AlexMamo

Comment: Use `task.getResult().size() == 0` if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
if (task.getResult().size() < 0) {
```

to

```
if (task.getResult().size() < 1) {
```

or

```
if (task.getResult().size() == 0) {
```

**The size of a list cannot be less than zero**